# Why does numpy.delete always delete one extra element in my test?

Tags: numpy

I want to use `numpy.delete` to delete certain elements in an array

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
bb = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype='bool')

np.delete(aa,bb)
```

gives me the results:

```
array([2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

I expect the results like this:

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

And if I change the `bb` to

```
bb = np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], dtype='bool')
```

I got:

```
np.delete(aa,bb)
array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

The code is simple, but I do not understand why numpy.delete behaves like this. Any explanations?

Comment: WIth a boolean mask like this you don't need `np.delete`.  Just use `aa[~bb]`.  As others noted pre 1.19 versions treat it as a integer delete,  not boolean.

Answer (score 1):

When I paste your code into a [repl](https://repl.it/@thshea/LightheartedIroncladDemo), I get the intended output. I am using Numpy v1.19.4 and Python 3.8.5. Check if there is an update for Numpy, and make sure that you are not doing any operations after that may remove the first item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

`np.delete` is using an array of ints as the indices to remove.  If you use a bool, that is converted to an int (False =0, True=1).  So what you are doing in your first example is saying remove the 0 index value and in the second example you have a 1 and a 0 so it's removing those indexes.

In the future numpy will not cast the booleans as integers.

`FutureWarning: in the future insert will treat boolean arrays and array-likes as boolean index instead of casting it to integer`